# Check fidelity of socket.io connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm having a project using socket.io and accepting connections from clients. However, I'm in doubt on how exactly I could check for the calls origin, as so every connection should be from my app and not from other services (in situations of hijack).

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

     console.log("socket",socket);

}
```

When an user connects, socket object displays a property named handshake.headers.host that looks like an IPv6 with the port. Would it suffice to check this property and act accordingly? Because I guess it could be spoofed, socket.io being open source and all... Does anyone have any other applicable idea? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For more security you should use https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio

Comment: I don't have awesomeSessionStore installed and can't find anything about it in the internet... how exactly can I install it?

Comment: this only placeholder, you can use any Session Store : Express-session or Redis-session. I usually use redis-session